# Assignable reference to both lvalues and rvalues

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a function `unique_count` that can count the number of unique elements in any *unsorted* range:

```
template<typename InputIt>
std::size_t unique_count(InputIt first, InputIt last)
{
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type;

    std::vector</* ??? */> v(first, last);
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    return std::distance(v.begin(),
                         std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()));
}
```

I create a new `vector` because I don't want to modify the original container, but I also don't want to do unnecessary copying. The easiest solution is to make a vector of pointers, but a problem is `*first` may return either a `const T&` (e.g., from a `vector`), or a `T` (e.g., from a stream).

The `/* ??? */` part should therefore be conceptually equivalent to `const T&`. We can't really do this, since `vector`s can't hold references, which are unassignable. We can't use `reference_wrapper<const T>` either, because it's not constructible from temporaries.

What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `/* ??? */` to be a type that may or may not own a `T` object, depending on whether it was constructed with a temporary `T` or a `const T&`. For obvious reasons, such types should generally be avoided.

One alternative is to use tag dispatch or SFINAE to select one of two possible implementations, depending on whether `*first` returns a reference or non-reference type.

Another alternative is to narrow your algorithm a bit so that it only accepts forward iterators. Here you are guaranteed to be able to simply store iterators themselves and use them to compare the elements pointed to:

```
template <typename ForwardIt>
std::size_t unique_count(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last) {
    std::vector<ForwardIt> v;
    for (auto i = first; i != last; ++i) {
        v.push_back(i);
    }
    const auto pred = [](ForwardIt a, ForwardIt b) { return *a < *b; };
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), pred);
    return std::distance(v.begin(), std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), pred));
}
```

Comment: Now I'm using `std::conditional` to select the vector value type between `T` and `reference_wrapper<const T>` depending on `is_lvalue_reference<decltype(*first)>::value`. Do you think this is a reasonable approach?

Comment: @ZizhengTai Sounds fine to me.